# setup:static-content:deploy fatal errors on XAMPP Windows7

Tags: magento2, xampp

When ever I run **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** it outputs the following error:

> Super13@Stone MINGW32 /d/xampp/htdocs/magento2-2.1.14 $ php
>   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy Requested languages: en_US
>   Requested areas: adminhtml, frontend Requested themes:
>   Magento/backend, Magento/blank, Magento/luma, Rahul/Theme1 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 15 passed to
>   Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy::__construct() must be of t 
>   array, null given, called in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-2.1.14\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFacto
>   on line 111 and defined in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-2.1.14\app\code\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy.php:177
>   Stack trace:
>   0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-2.1.14\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Magento\Deploy
>   Deploy\LocaleDeploy->__construct(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput),
>   Object(Magento\Translation\Model\Js\Con
>   bject(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View RepositoryFactory),
>   Object(Magento\RequireJs\Model\FileManagerFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\RequireJs\ConfigFactory), Objec
>   to\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager), Object(Ma in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\magent
>   14\app\code\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy.php on line 177
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 15 passed to
>   Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy::__construct() must be of the
>   ty y, null given, called in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-2.1.14\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.ph
>   ne 111 and defined in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-2.1.14\app\code\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy.php:177
>   Stack trace:
>   0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-2.1.14\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Magento\Deploy
>   Deploy\LocaleDeploy->__construct(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput),
>   Object(Magento\Translation\Model\Js\Con
>   bject(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View RepositoryFactory),
>   Object(Magento\RequireJs\Model\FileManagerFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\RequireJs\ConfigFactory), Objec
>   to\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager), Object(Ma in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\magent
>   14\app\code\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy.php on line 177

This is with Magento 2.1.1 , XAMPP,Windows7.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the wrong ownership. So please assign correct user and web group to the project directory. 
I have followed these steps in my ubuntu OS

```
cd <root directory of magento>

find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chown -R magento:www-data .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Restart the apache server then it should work.

Comment: Can you please share commands to assign correct user and web group to the project directory in Xampp,Windows7

Comment: cd <root directory of your project>
chown -R magento:www-data .
 here magento is user and www-data is the web group.

Comment: Hi, Im getting error - Super13@Stone MINGW32 /d/xampp/htdocs/magento2-2.1.14
$ chown -R magento:www-data .
chown: invalid user: ‘magento:www-data’

Comment: magento is my system's user, you can use your user name instead of magento

Comment: Getting this error now- Super13@Stone MINGW32 /d/xampp/htdocs/magento2-2.1.14
$ chown -R Super13:www-data .
chown: invalid group: ‘Super13:www-data’

Comment: usermod -g www-data Super13                                                                            Please run this cmd to associate the user with the group.

Comment: Getting this error Super13@Stone MINGW32 /d/xampp/htdocs/magento2-2.1.14
$ usermod -g www-data Super13
bash: usermod: command not found